# How to get client files in Java bean?

Tags: java, file, get, client, oracle-adf

I develop a web application using JDeveloper. Then, my scenario is I want to get a file from client directory (e.g. C://Image.jpg). What I want to achieve is the client's directory defined programmatically. So, I used InputStream, but it will search a file in server directory. if I used UploadedFile, I don't know how to define it. Note that I don't want to use InputFile.

Does anyone have a solution for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for HTTP File Upload. You need an `<input type='file'>` control on your webpage, and form encoding set as `enctype='multipart/form-data'`.

Generally, you can't control the default directory where the browser is going to open a file chooser -- it normally starts from the "user home" directory, but other dirs can be navigated to.

Comment: Hi @thomas-w.

I used ADF framework. And what I want to get the client's file programmatically (java class). So there is no UI to input the file.

Do have any idea ?

Comment: No UI?  Every black-hat hacker in the world would like to read your bank details & personal files, without a pesky UI being needed **for users to select the files genuinely wish to upload.**

Comment: I meant my scenario is the user upload an excel file that contains the path directory of each file that I have to copy to the server. Or we can say automatically upload.

Comment: **Not possible from a browser app.**  Why not just get them to upload a ZIP of the files they want processed, rather than fooling round with Excel? Enough of this question.

Comment: That was my second plan. upload the files in ZIP. Thanks for the idea